# Proving formula for length of crossed product

Tags: cross-product

Suppose we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and have the defined the usual scalar product and proven Cauchy-Schwarz. Then we can define the angle, $\theta$, between non-zero vectors by requiring $a\cdot b= |a||b| \cos(\theta)$. (We assume we have defined $\cos$ analytically and proven all the usual properties.)

If I then define the cross product, $a\times b$, using the usual coordinate formula how do I prove that $|a\times b| = |a| |b| \sin(\theta)$?

Comment: have you tried expanding the coordinates formulaes ? ($(ya*zb - yb*za)^2 + ...$)

Comment: you need to show that $|a X b|^2 + | a . b|^2 = ||a||^2 * ||b||^2$. Tiring but you should get there

Comment: Here's a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/proof-relationship-between-cross-product-and-sin-of-angle) (from Kahn academy) going though this proof.